# TypeError: Can't dup NilClass while downloading file using remote_file

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I am trying to download a file(for java install) from a http server. I have the below in my recipe.

```
remote_file "Downloading Java from: #{dl_url}" do
    source  dl_url
    path    java_dlfile
    owner   user
    group   group
    mode    0664
    backup false
    action :create_if_missing
    not_if { Dir.exists?(java_home) }
end
```

It is throwing downloading java from http://opscics.com/1.2.0__jdk-7u55-fcs-bin-b13-linux-x64-17_mar_2014.tar.gz

TypeError: Can't dup NilClass

The file is available at that location & I am able to access it & download from my browser.

What could be the problem.

Comment: I am also seeing block in send_http_request

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace. Is dl_url set to that URL you mentioned? What's path set to, etc?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. One / was missing after http: in the url. Thanks.